# How to get store information in Ebay API with sandbox credentials?

Tags: integration, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

We're implementing integration with Ebay as following:

1. User goes to our site and presses the button.
2. The user is redirected to the authentication page of Ebay, logs in and approves grant of permissions (OAuth).
3. Then we receive the code and exchange it to tokens.

After that with that tokens we need to access store information such as store name, products of the store, orders of the store.

I'm trying to test the calls to `GetStore` API of Ebay with sandbox user credentials. But I get the `Unknown error`.

Here is the documentation for the method I call, and it says we need to call `SetStore` first for sandbox users. But the documentation for the method doesn't exist and the call to the method returns `Unknown error`:
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetStore.html

Comment: SetStore was removed in API version 1267. Trying to use 1257 results in the same error. The sandbox site is barely functioning with most pages redirecting away from the sandbox, including user settings. There is apparently no way to give new sandbox users a store subscription. Did you ever find a solution?